# Need help using xpath in Karate UI

Tags: karate

I'm facing issue in using xpath while running KarateUi test

```
Feature: testRun
    Scenario: google search
    Given driver 'http://google.com'
    Then waitForUrl('https://google.com')
    When if(locate("//input[@name='q']").exists) 
    input("//input[name='q']",'testing')
    And click('input[name=btnK]')
    Then waitFor('{h3}Software testing - Wikipedia')
```

I get the below error

```
javascript evaluation failed: if(locate("//input[@name='q']").exists) input("//input[name='q']",'testing'), failed to get reply for: [id: 8, method: Runtime.evaluate, params: {expression=var e = document.evaluate("//input[name='q']", document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue; e.focus(); try { e.selectionStart = e.selectionEnd = e.value.length } catch(x) {}, returnByValue=true}]
```

I would appreciate if some one can help me with what's missing in the above scenario

Thanks
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

Please use the correct css locator:

```
Given driver 'http://google.com'
And input("input[name='q']", 'testing')
And click('input[name=btnK]')
Then waitFor('{h3}Software testing - Wikipedia')
```

Also please read this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1148

Comment: Thanks Peter for the quick response, Just curious as to why the xpath is not working, I actually need to validate all the elements in the left nav which are siblings of a particular element which is found using containstext   Thanks in advance for your support

Comment: this also works for me: `input("//input[@name='q']", 'testing')`